# Text Being Replaced Automatically in VSC 1.79

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I primarily work with C# code and since updating to VSC 1.79 am experiencing odd behavior.

With the following line of code:

```
public string EmailSubject = new();
```

If I click next to the left of the `s` in `string` and type `List\<`, the line becomes:

```
public List< EmailSubject = new();
```

Previously, `string` would remain in place and I could jump to its end with `Ctrl+Right` and add `\>` to complete the change.

```
public List<string> EmailSubjects = new();
```

It seems it's related to "Quick suggestions", as referenced in the Release Notes, but I can't seem to find a configuration that restores behavior to what I am accustomed. Tried messing with `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions`, `editor.suggest.selectionMode`, `editor.inlineSuggest...`, and various others without luck.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: Using quite a few extensions. Disabled them all except the [official C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) from Microsoft. No change.

Solved: This was caused by a [breaking change in 1.79.2 that triggers completion inside words #2542](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/2542).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Does this require extensions to reproduce? Are you sure you didn't just switch your keyboard to insert mode?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, I disabled all extensions except for C# (which is required for what I'm doing) and the same behavior is there. Also, double-checked that I am in Insert mode by using another program. A while back I disabled the Insert key via AHK. I suppose it's useful to someone but I've never met any of them. That said, the placement of the key changed from a prior keyboard and I kept hitting it :-(

As a little more information, this appears to be limited to C# documents (ie. .cs files). The behavior does not happen in settings.json, .gitignore, .txt files, etc.

Comment: please add version info for your C# extension. And the Extensions marketplace page URL.

Comment: It's the official C# extension from Microsoft and was installed through VS Code. Website appears to be "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp".

Comment: Thank you for the response @starball, but this is already solved. It was marked in my first post about a week ago. What you posted points to the exact issue. It was a VS Code bug and it appears that multiple people created tickets in Github for it. You found one and I found another. I wanted to mark the thread as solved, but I see no way to do that. Even after looking up how to mark threads as solved. There is no gray checkmark anywhere on the page :-(

Comment: if you agree that this question post is a duplicate, then click the button that says to accept that it is a duplicate :)